# c# How to call and handle a custom generic event arg?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

hoping someone could lend a hand here. I have a custom even argument that contains a collection. I can build the event arg but I cannot implement it. I want to put the event handler in the base class and override it in my derived classes.

The even arg:

```
public class ImportEventArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Data { get; }

    public ImportEventArgs(IEnumerable<T> data)
    {
        Data = data;
    }
}
```

The part in my base class that is not resolving:

```
public virtual void EventHandler<EventArgs> ImportComplete;
```

The override:

```
override void EventHandler<WellPathImportEventArgs<WellPath>> ImportComplete;
```

I figured this is not the correct way of doing this, could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: If this is wpf, why do you have an event handler at all?  Usually MVVM means you don't have code like you seem to want to write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change a method's signature when you override it.

However, since all event args derive from the same type, you don't have to. Just keep the existing method definition and cast the argument, like this:

```
public override void ImportComplete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myEventArgs = e as ImportEventArgs<WellPath>;
    if (myEventArgs != null)
    {
        foreach (var item in myEventArgs.Data)
        {
            //Your code here
        }
    }
}
```